# python : tracking change in class to save it at the end

Tags: python, class, object

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.db = create_db_object()

    def change_Db_a(self):
         self.db.change_something()
         self.db.save()

    def change_db_b(self):
         self.db.change_anotherthing()
         self.db.save()
```

I am getting object from database, I changing it in multiple function and saving it back. 
which is slow because it hits database on every function call. is there anything like deconstructor where I can save the database object so that I don't have to save it for every function call and not waste time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't rely on the `__del__` method for saving your object.  For details, see this [blog post](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/06/12/safely-using-destructors-in-python/).

You can use use the [context management protocol](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#context-manager-types) by defining `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods:

```
class A(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        print 'enter'
        # create database object here (or in __init__)
        pass

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        print 'exit'
        # save database object here

    # other methods
```

Then use the `with` statement when you create your object:

```
with A() as myobj:
    print 'inside with block'
    myobj.do_something()
```

When you enter the `with` block, the `A.__enter__` method will be called.  When you exit the `with` block the `__exit__` method will be called.  For example, with the code above you should see the following output:

> enter
>
> inside with block
>
> exit

Here's more information on the `with` statement:

- [Understanding Python's "with" statement](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm)

Comment: It gives me error that , AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'db'

Comment: Hard to say since I can't see your code (there's no `db` in the code I wrote above). But are you sure you initialized your `db` variable?  Are you missing the `self`?  Sounds like a different problem though, so maybe you should start a new question and post some code.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a **del** method.

```
def __del__(self):
    self.db.save()
```

But note that this violates data consistency.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I wanted. One more question : How to detect change in db ?  so that , If nothing changed, I do not unnecessarily save object to database on every del.

Comment: You can overload `__setattr__` in your class and set flag on its call. Then check that flag at `__del__`.